# Fancybox PDF issue in Firefox

Tags: firefox, pdf, popup, fancybox

I have Fancybox set up so that when a user clicks on a pdf link it displays the pdf in a pop up, however in Firefox it asks if you want to save or open the file and I don't want this. How can I force the pdf to be display in the fancybox popup? It works in Safari.

```
<a class="pdf" href="http://www.test.co.u.uk/test.pdf">test.pdf</a>

$(".pdf").fancybox({
   'width' : '700',
   'height' : '700',
   'autoScale' : true,
   'transitionIn' : 'none',
   'transitionOut' : 'none',
   'type' : 'iframe'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would just use Google Docs to display the PDF in an iframe. It automatically resizes the PDF to match the iframe dimensions. Here is the format to use:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:100%; height:100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

You don't need flash or any other plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the PDF file to HTML, or try to turn the PDF into an image.

I had this issue but I wasn't able to change my server settings to display PDF files instead of prompting them for download.

There is also variations between browsers the way they read PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the user has a plug-in that renders PDF installed, the PDF won't render inline in Firefox.  It's just not a format Firefox natively supports at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you don't have the pdf plugin installed in Firefox or the plugin just crashed.

In Firefox, go to `Tools` --> `Add-ons` -->`Plugins` and look for Adobe Acrobat PDF plugin in the list. If isn't there, [check this](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Using%20the%20Adobe%20Reader%20plugin%20with%20Firefox#w_installing-and-updating-adobe-reader) to learn how to install it (or re-install it).

Additionally, there is a better way to open PDF files with fancybox other than iframe, so for this html:

```
<a class="pdf" href="http://www.test.co.u.uk/test.pdf">test.pdf</a>
```

you can use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".pdf").click(function() {
  $.fancybox({
   'width': '70%', // or whatever
   'height': '90%',
   'autoDimensions': false,
   'content': '<embed src="'+this.href+'#nameddest=self&page=1&view=FitH,0&zoom=80,0,0" type="application/pdf" height="99%" width="100%" />',
   'onClosed': function() {
     $("#fancybox-inner").empty();
   }
  });
  return false;
 }); // pdf 
}); // ready
```

I recommended this method for Fancybox v1.3.x since [May 2010](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/43b8119fa8a12735/2257)

Please notice that I set height="99%". If you use HTML5 DCTYPE, it will avoid a double vertical scroll bar. This is because HTML5 initializes margins.

**UPDATE**.
BTW, integer values go without qoutes so

```
'width' : '700',
'height' : '700',
```

should be

```
'width' : 700,
'height' : 700,
```

It will save you some headaches,mostly with IE