# Not able to display PDF using fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Html code

```
<div class="casestudy">//$casestudyDocData=http://localhost/xxxx/case/interview_questionarie.pdf

<iframe src="<?php echo $casestudyDocData; ?>"  width="395" height="195"> </iframe> 

<a class="fancypdf" href="<?php echo $casestudyDocData; ?>" >Link to PDF </a>
```

jquery code

```
$(".fancypdf").fancybox({
                'frameWidth': 680,
                'frameHeight':495,
                'overlayShow':true,
                'hideOnContentClick':false
});
```

I am using fancybox to display the pdf The requested content cannot be loaded.

Please try again later. But fancybox is not able to display the pdf? Can anyone find what is the mistake i have done ?

Comment: perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/best-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html

Comment: PDF can be displayed without converting to png in fancybox

Comment: Not on every browser it can't.

Comment: Fine can u find out what is the problem in my code

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/8806294/1055987 I guess you should use the search option to look for similar questions before you post a new issue.

Comment: Also, try to format your code properly. Use the help while you edit.

Comment: @JFK TRUE ... the mistake was just needed to add type: iframe

Comment: JFK I used my iPhone to post the question so couldn't format the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U should just use 'type':'iframe'

```
$(".fancypdf").fancybox({
                'frameWidth': 680,
                'frameHeight':495,
                'overlayShow':true,
                'hideOnContentClick':false,
                'type':'iframe'
});
```